# Optimize string comparison in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string-comparison

I have the following code on an asp.net button click

```
if(str == ipaddr1 || ipaddr2 || ipaddr3 || ipaddr4 || ipaddr5 || ipaddr6 || ipaddr7)
// do this
else
//cancel click event
```

How can I optimize this piece of code?

**Update:** Apologies everyone! I did not mean to compare it with the literal string ipaddr. I mean to compare it to the value ipaddr1, ipaddr2 holds and so on

Comment: Optimize for what? Performance? Readability? Maintainability?

Comment: Note that your example only compares `str` to `"ipaddr1"`. This is likely a mistake.

Comment: is it possible to push those ipaddrX into a string list, you would have them together also instead of keeping diff values\

Comment: I have updated my question. I want to compare str with the value of all these strings

Comment: Again, you're just comparing `str` and `ipaddr1`. You have to write `str == ipaddr1 || str == ipaddr2 || ...`

Comment: @Matt Kraven - That changes everything totally. See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HashSet<T>` is the best container to check containing:

```
var ips = new HashSet<string> { "ip1", "ip2", "ip3", "ip4", "ip5" };
if (ips.Contains(input))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

---

For any type:

```
var ips = new HashSet<IPHostEntry> { ip1, ip2, ip3, ip4, ip5 };
if (ips.Contains(input))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

---

Was:

```
if(str = qry.StartsWith("23.55") || str = qry.StartsWith("xuz") || str = qry.StartsWith("i3") || str = qry.StartsWith("i444") || str = qry.StartsWith("ki5") || str = qry.StartsWith("65fr6")) // do this else // do this
```

Become:

```
var arr = new[] { "23.55", "xuz", "i3",  "i444", "ki5", "65fr6") };
if (arr.Any(str => input.StartsWith(str, StringComparison.Ordinal))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

`StringComparison.Ordinal` or `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` are very important for performance.

Comment: thanks you. I have another similar problem. How to optimize this code? if(str = qry.StartsWith("23.55") || str = qry.StartsWith("xuz") || str = qry.StartsWith("i3") || str = qry.StartsWith("i444") || str = qry.StartsWith("ki5") || str = qry.StartsWith("65fr6"))
// do this
else
// do this

Comment: @Matt: I updated my post. Also you tilde to highlight `source code` into comments

Comment: thanks I need more clarification please. What is input and str and how will i use them? I want to compare X with a set of strings to see if X begins with the value any of these strings contain? Probaby I am not able to convey my question correctly. Thanks for being patient.

Comment: I am thinking do I really need str here. Why not just do if(qry.StartsWith("23.55") || qry.StartsWith("xuz") || ...)

Comment: @Matt: `Any()` is LINQ extension method, `(str => ..)` is lambda expression http://bit.ly/fH3RZN `input` is a variable, string to compare, what you call `qry`, what ever.

Answer (score 4):

replace with:

```
Regex.IsMatch(str, "^ipaddr[1-7]$")
```

Optimised for **readability** not necessarily performance.

Comment: I am sorry. I realized i confused everyone by posting the wrong string. question updated

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like:

```
str.Length == 7 && str.StartsWith("ipaddr") && str[6] > '0' && str[6] < '8'
```

**Edit**:

After your update, I would do something like:

```
string[] validStrings = { ipaddr1, ipaddr2, ... };
bool isStrValid = validStrings.Contains(str);
```

For better performance, consider using a `HashSet<string>` instead of an array, especially if the list of valid strings doesn't change.

Comment: Checking containing against an array is definitely slow - O(n)

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
if(str.Substring(0,6) == "ipaddr" && str[6] >= '1' && str[6] <= '7')
```

For your information, your original code does not even compile. This

```
if(str == "ipaddr1" || "ipaddr2" || "ipaddr3" || "ipaddr4" || "ipaddr5" || "ipaddr6" || "ipaddr7")
```

Needs to be replaced with this to compile

```
if(str == "ipaddr1" || str == "ipaddr2" || str == "ipaddr3" || str == "ipaddr4" || str == "ipaddr5" || str == "ipaddr6" || str == "ipaddr7")
```

So the original code is actually even more tedious than you thought.

**UPDATE**

According to your updated question, the best option is to put your string variables into a `List<string>` called, for example `ipaddr`. Then to see if the string `str` is included, simply do this:

```
if( ipaddr.Contains( str ) )
{
   //contained in the list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do a

```
List<string> variables = new List<string> { "ip1","ip2","ip3","ip4","ip5" };

if (variables.Contains(inputstring))
  ...
```

Comment: Well.. This answer may be valid then... (again?) :p

Comment: Checking containing against array or `List<T>` is definitely slow - O(n)

Comment: On which scenario is it slow? Comparing seven items with short strings. I will check youre hashset way to do it. Interesting.

Comment: Regarding performance and .Contains(), it's still has limitation on 2100 items, when used against a sql query?

Answer (score 0):

Both more readable, and more performant would be:

```
switch(str)
{
case "ipaddr1": 
case "ipaddr2":
case "ipaddr3":
case "ipaddr4":
case "ipaddr5":
case "ipaddr6":
case "ipaddr7":
    //do something
    break;
default:
    //do something else
    break;
}
```

(although, admittedly massively verbose...)